# Uploading a file to a VarBinaryMax field into Windows Azure?

Tags: sql, azure

I'm extremely confused, so I've created an SQL Database in Windows Azure, created a "video table" with a "video_file" column as "varbinary(max)" because I want to upload a video file into that field, however Azure offers no "Upload" option like say, PHPMyAdmin does where you can hit "browse" and upload a video directly into the field. Can anyone guide me as to how to actually upload a file into a Windows Azure SQL Database so it can be read as a varbinary type? Can it be done within the Azure management portal? Or does it require some sort of external program/service?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, the functionality to upload files directly into SQL Azure Database does not exist. This is something you have to do on your own.

> Can anyone guide me as to how to actually upload a file into a Windows
>   Azure SQL Database so it can be read as a varbinary type?

Do a search for uploading files in SQL Server and you will find plenty of examples on how to do that. Take a look at this link for example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/225446/Uploading-and-downloading-files-to-from-a-SQL-Serv

> Can it be done within the Azure management portal? Or does it require some sort of external program/service?

No. This functionality does not exist in Azure Management Portal. As mentioned above, you would need to write some code to do so.

A little bit off-topic comment:

May I suggest that instead of saving the image files in the database you save them in **`Blob Storage`** and store the URL of the blob in your table. There're some advantages I could see in this:

- Compared to SQL Database, Azure Blob Storage is much cheaper. If you store video files (or in other words large files) in the database, you will end up with large database and thus end up paying more money.
- You will be choking the database when reading this large data from the database which will impact the performance of your application.

Comment: Thank you for your response Gaurav,  I came across that link you posted before, and I was unsure as to how to adapt the code to fit Azure SQL server parameters, that code assumes you have a normal local SQL server stored as a SDF as opposed to one  in the cloud.

Comment: As per your second suggestion, I do have the file stored as a BLOB to, however in my Windows Phone 8 application, I have had the consistent problem of not being able to find a way to "call" or "parse" the URL from the relevant Azure SQL Table and column, as I do not know how to go about writing the Syntax for this and this has been a problem for quite some time now even after a lot of google searching and asking etc. The URL needs to be "called"/"parsed" from the relevant column and bought to display into the application as a MediaElement, could you assist with this at all?

Comment: Haven't worked with mobile apps so I may be wrong but I quickly looked up `MediaElement` documentation on MSDN and found it has a property called `PosterSource` which takes a URI. Now assuming that the blob container which is storing the image has `Public` ACL, then you can simply set the Blob URL as value for this PosterSource. Things may become a bit complicated if you have the blob container's ACL as `Private`. Then you would need to create a `Shared Access Signature` URL with `Read` permission on the blob and use that URL as value for PosterSource. HTH.

Comment: Ah yes I just checked that out, unfortunately that only works with Windows Phone 8.1 or above and I have just a Windows Phone 8.0 that uses the "source" property, which links directly to the file in application storage or via a direct URL if stored as raw on a file system.